# Salesforce Spring'20 mascot

Tags: trailhead

This is totally a non-technical question. But I'm trying to search more about the Spring'20 mascot. I believe it's a FOX not a Raccoon.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's a **WOLF** named *Blaze*.

Read more about the character names [here](https://namingschemes.com/Salesforce_Trailhead_Characters)